# javascript giving wrong date after conversion from string to date in IE 8

Tags: javascript, date

I'm having date from my app in the format eg.

`2013-05-01T00:00:00`

when i'm converting this to Date

```
var d = '2013-05-01T00:00:00'
var result = new Date(d);
```

getting `result` as `NaN`

when i do,

`var result = new Date(d.replace(/-/g, '/'));`

getting result as,

`Tue Apr 30 22:30:00 UTC+0530 2013`

what could be the reason that i'm getting date 1 day before..

Comment: Do not leave parsing of date strings to the Date constructor, it is too unreliable. **Always** parse strings yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always parse date strings yourself, browsers are notoriously bad at it. For examle, some browsers will treat '2013-05-01T00:00:00' as UTC and others as local. It **should** be [treated as UTC](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) (since the timezone is missing), so:

```
function parseDateString(s) {
    s = s.match(/\d+/g);
    return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], (s[6] || 0));
}
```

which will create a date object using the above values as UTC and with a timezone offset based on current system settings. So if your current timezone is UTC+0530, you should get the equivalent of:

```
2013-05-01T05:30:00+0530
```

however you seem to be getting a value for UTC-0130. I have no clue about that.

Oh, when you do:

```
new Date(d.replace(/-/g, '/'));
```

you are totally mangling the string so it is not an ISO 8601 string and you are completely at the mercy of an implementation dependent date parser (i.e. every implementation may be different, if that's possible).