# HighCharts with Series datet/time

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

```
[{"name":"M3","data":[["2014-04-16 23:03:59","0"],["2014-04-15 17:48:37","0"],["2014-04-15 17:43:16","1"],["2014-04-15 17:42:52","0"],["2014-04-15 17:36:19","1"],["2014-04-15 17:35:43","0"],["2014-04-15 17:35:31","0"],["2014-04-15 17:30:22","0"],["2014-04-15 17:27:47","1"],["2014-04-15 17:26:00","1"],["2014-04-15 17:19:28","1"],["2014-04-15 17:00:26","0"],["2014-04-15 16:53:18","0"]]},{"name":"M2","data":[["2014-04-16 23:03:47","0"],["2014-04-15 17:47:25","0"],["2014-04-15 17:33:20","1"],["2014-04-15 17:30:10","0"],["2014-04-15 16:57:51","0"]]},{"name":"M1","data":[["2014-04-15 17:47:37","0"],["2014-04-15 17:45:15","0"]]}]
```

The above is the JSON data for HighCHarts wherein I need to set the X axis to date/time and Y to status . The JSON is generated and attached to the series property and is used as below: This is not plotting at all.

```
var handlerURL = "http://localhost:50687/Handler.ashx?";
        $.ajax({
            url: handlerURL,
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            complete: function (json) {
                jsonData = json.responseText; alert(jsonData);
            }

        });
        options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 50
            },

            setOptions: ({
                global: { useUTC: true }
            }),

            title: {
                text: 'Live Data',
                x: -20
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -30
            },
            xAxis: {

                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 100,
                plotLines: [{
                    width: 5,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0, max: 1,
                title: {
                    text: 'Status'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.x + ': ' + this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: []
        }

        options.series = jsonData;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });
```

Comment: You might get some help from [*Starting Time Series Highcharts Plot at specific date/time*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062152/starting-time-series-highcharts-plot-at-specific-date-time?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks Rob, my JSON is having the data in String for both date and status. That is because in the backend it is formatted like that . I believe Highchart i snot able to recognize the same

Comment: Cool, parsing the string to a Date object is [pretty easy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803021/javascript-giving-wrong-date-after-conversion-from-string-to-date-in-ie-8/22803399#22803399). Don't leave it up to the browser as some will treat strings without a timezone as UTC and others as local (and the string you're providing isn't strictly conformant with ES5, though it's close enough that most browsers will process it but a few wont).

Comment: Tried the conversion, but chart comes up blank

Comment: How you coverse, any live demo?

Comment: Another problem you will have is that your Y values are set as strings in your JSON. You will need to use parseInt() or parseFloat() in order for the chart to recognize them as numeric values.